# Error occurred in appDelegate method

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

Error occurred in appDelegate.m file while i run the sample signal aborted at

```
self.view.controller=root.view.controller
```

please help me i added code below

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /* bad signal occurred at this line */
    self.window.rootViewController=self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIWindow rootViewController property doesn't exist before iOS4. If you're trying to run this code on an device with iOS 3 or older, it will crash.

In your AppDelegate, you can use addSubview instead.

`//self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController; // Only iOS >= 4
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for `self.view.controller = root.view.controller` is a bit weird. I think you mean `self.viewController = rootViewController` ? Even so, that is incorrect.

Try something like -

```
self.viewController = [[YourViewController alloc]init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Replace YourViewController with the class of your controller.